# Ruby fetch few lines before the regular expression pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

i am tailing a file and catchinga  regular expression. However i want 4 lines before the regular patter.

example input:

```
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  .....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  tx=1111 ....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  - Invoking API time=515ms
     -> Invoked URL: 'http://........'
     -> Authorization: ....
     -> Request: blah blah request
     <- Response: 201 - Success
```

i want to fetch tx=1111 for each Response: 201

is it possible to do this? can i use positive lookback?

Comment: What is a (regular) patter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with regexp followed by filtering the result:

```
input.
  scan(/(tx=\d+).*?Response:\s+(\d+)/m).
  select { |_, resp| resp == '201' }.
  map(&:first)
#⇒ ["tx=1111"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the string is as follows.

```
str =<<BITTER_END
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  .....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  tx=1111 ....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  - Invoking API time=515ms
     -> Invoked URL: 'http://........'
     -> Authorization: ....
     -> Request: blah blah request
     <- Response: 201 - Success
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  .....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  tx=1112 ....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  - Invoking API time=515ms
     -> Invoked URL: 'http://........'
     -> Authorization: ....
     -> Request: blah blah request
     <- Response: 202 - Success
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  .....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  tx=1113 ....
2018-09-28 00:00:01 INFO  - Invoking API time=515ms
     -> Invoked URL: 'http://........'
     -> Authorization: ....
     -> Request: blah blah request
     <- Response: 201 - Success
BITTER_END
```

My understanding is that we wish to return (an array of) the values of `tx` when they are followed (after a few lines) by `<- Response: 201`. If that is correct, we wish to return `["1111", "1113"]`, but not `"1112"` because that is followed by `<- Response: 202`.

That can be done with a straightforward regular expression if we first reverse the string, causing it to appear as follows (the result of `puts str.reverse`).

```
sseccuS - 102 :esnopseR -<
tseuqer halb halb :tseuqeR >-
.... :noitazirohtuA >-
'........//:ptth' :LRU dekovnI >-
sm515=emit IPA gnikovnI -  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
.... 3111=xt  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
.....  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
sseccuS - 202 :esnopseR -<
tseuqer halb halb :tseuqeR >-
.... :noitazirohtuA >-
'........//:ptth' :LRU dekovnI >-
sm515=emit IPA gnikovnI -  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
.... 2111=xt  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
.....  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
sseccuS - 102 :esnopseR -<
tseuqer halb halb :tseuqeR >-
.... :noitazirohtuA >-
'........//:ptth' :LRU dekovnI >-
sm515=emit IPA gnikovnI -  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
.... 1111=xt  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
.....  OFNI 10:00:00 82-90-8102
```

Our regular expression is as follows.

```
r = /
    [ ]102[ ]:esnopseR[ ]-<  # match reverse of `'<- Response: 201'      
    .+?                      # match one or more characters, lazily
    [ ]                      # match a space
    (\d+)                    # match one or more digits in capture group 1
    =xt[ ][ ]OFNI            # match '=xt  OFNI'
    /xm                      # free-spacing and multiline modes
```

(I've written it in free-spacing mode it order to document each element.)<sup>1</sup> We can then extract the desired values using [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan).

```
str.reverse.scan(r).flatten.map(&:reverse).reverse
  #=> ["1111", "1113"]
```

We first obtain the following.

```
str.reverse.scan(r)
  #=> [["3111"], ["1111"]]
```

As we want `["1111", "1113"]`, we must flatten this array, reverse each string and then reverse the order of the reversed strings.

<sup><sub>1. This regular expression is conventionally written `/ 102 :esnopseR -<.+? (\d+)=xt  OFNI/m`. Spaces are removed in free-spacing mode, which is why each space is enclosed in a character class when the `/x` option is used. To minimize mistakes it might be better to write `/#{'<- Response: 201 '.reverse}.+? (\d+)#{'INFO  tx='.reverse}/m`.</sub></sup>